# Is it allowed to see prank videos

Tags: halal-haram, sin

Assalamualaikum I know it is haram to prank anyone my question is is it allowed to see prank videos in youtube just for entertainment purpose
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The act of watching a video itself is not Haram, *as long as the content is not Haram*, yet wasting time watching non-useful videos or videos that might lead you to commit a sin if you persist to watch them (i.e, videos that make your heart die), is not recommended in Islam because our prophet Muhammad (PBUH) said:

> A slave of Allah will remain standing on the Day of Judgement till he
> is questioned about (four things) his life on earth and **how he spent
> it**, and about his knowledge and how he utilized it, and his wealth
> and how he acquired it and in what way did he spend it, and about his
> body and how he wore it out.